# What workaround in Regex (Zotero) to ENG\s+DOGS matches ENG DOGS or ENGDOGS?

Tags: regex, space

Expression expects line breaks and spaces, but they couldn't appear too. `0` space possibility.

`ENG\s+DOGS` need to match:

```
ENG DOGS 

ENGDOGS 

ENG [line break]
DOGS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
/ENG\s*DOGS/

Match the characters “ENG” literally «ENG»
Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks) «\s*»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
Match the characters “DOGS” literally «DOGS»
```

Comment: So dogs/ and dogs \bdogs are equal?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `*` quantifier instead.

```
ENG\s*DOGS
```

Regular expression:

```
ENG           # 'ENG'
 \s*          # whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times)
 DOGS         # 'DOGS'
```

The following quantifiers are recognized.

```
*      Match 0 or more times
+      Match 1 or more times
?      Match 1 or 0 times
{n}    Match exactly n times
{n,}   Match at least n times
{n,m}  Match at least n but not more than m times
```